# Not able to create maps of map

Tags: java

I am trying  to create maps of map in java inorder to show all the pri status by reading the unix command line output .

Here is my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.StringTokenizer;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import java.util.*;
public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String args[]) {

        String s = null;

        try {

            Process p1 = Runtime.getRuntime().exec( new String[] {"asterisk", "-rx", "pri show spans"});            
            BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(p1.getInputStream()));
            Map mainpri = new HashMap();
            BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new
            InputStreamReader(p1.getErrorStream()));
            int count = 1;
            while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
                if(count > 2)
                {
                //Map pristatus = new HashMap();
                Hashtable<Integer, String> sourceone = new Hashtable<Integer,String>();
                HashMap<Integer, String>  pristatus = new HashMap(sourceone);

                System.out.println(s);
                 StringTokenizer st = new StringTokenizer(s);
                int nextcount = 1;
                 while (st.hasMoreTokens()) {
                      if(nextcount == 1){
                       pristatus.put(1, st.nextToken());

                       }
                      else if(nextcount == 2){
                       pristatus.put(2, st.nextToken());

                      }
                      else if(nextcount == 3){
                       pristatus.put(3, st.nextToken());
                      }
                      else  if(nextcount == 4){
                           pristatus.put(4, st.nextToken());

                      }
                      else{
                         pristatus.put(5, st.nextToken());

                      }

                    nextcount ++ ;  

                 }
                    mainpri.put(1,pristatus);
                    System.out.println(mainpri);

                }
                count ++;
            }

            while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
                System.out.println(s);
            }

            System.exit(0);
        }
        catch (IOException e) {
            System.out.println("exception happened - here's what I know: ");
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.exit(-1);
        }
    }
}
```

after generating the pristatus  map I am trying to add that value in form of key value in mainpri map

But instead of adding the data my above code always

```
{1={1=PRI, 2=span, 3=1/0:, 4=Up,, 5=Active}}
{1={1=PRI, 2=span, 3=2/0:, 4=In, 5=Active}}
{1={1=PRI, 2=span, 3=3/0:, 4=In, 5=Active}}
{1={1=PRI, 2=span, 3=4/0:, 4=In, 5=Active}}
```

But i want this to be in

```
{1={1=PRI, 2=span, 3=1/0:, 4=Up,, 5=Active},
{2={1=PRI, 2=span, 3=2/0:, 4=In, 5=Active},
{3={1=PRI, 2=span, 3=3/0:, 4=In, 5=Active},
{4={1=PRI, 2=span, 3=4/0:, 4=In, 5=Active}}
```

I am python turned java developer so I am not able to figure out I read about Hastable but that doesn't work .

Please help me out What might I am doing wrong .

Comment: If I read the two output blocks correctly, your problem is only one of missing commas? Also, use HashMap whenever something old says Hashtable.

Comment: no }  is also missing

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should change this line:

```
mainpri.put(1,pristatus);
```

to:

```
mainpri.put(count, pristatus);
```

As you want to change the map key.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Collections.addAll method when you initiallize de map

Answer (score 0):

You've hard coded the key of mainpri to 1, you should use the "count" variable instead of "1"

```
mainpri.put(1,pristatus);
```

Answer (score 0):

As correctly pointed out the problem is in this line -:
**mainpri.put(1,pristatus);**
You are always putting the value against the key 1,
instead replace it with -:
mainpri.put(count,pristatus);

Answer (score 0):

You need to change the map key value from 1 to count value

**mainpri.put(1,pristatus)**

to

**mainpri.put(count,pristatus)**